Why celery doesn't run the code and how can I fix it?
I'm developing an API in Django; for this API I need to use celery to do delayed actions. Eventually, the aim would be to remove data from the database after a certain period of inactivity. I've set up celery and Rabbitmq, but when I try to execute something with a print to try nothing happens.
Here's how I set up celery in settings.py:
#celery settings
import ssl
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqps://guest:guest@localhost:5671/'
CELERY_BROKER_USE_SSL = {
  'ca_certs': '/etc/rabbitmq/cacert.crt',
  'keyfile': '/etc/rabbitmq/key.pem',
  'certfile': '/etc/rabbitmq/cert.crt',
  'cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
}
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "rpc://"

Here's the code I'm trying to run:
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

#DELAY_FOR_DATA_DELETION = timedelta(days=30)  # 30 jours par exemple

@shared_task
def delete_user():
    print("test")
    return

that's how I call the function:
delete_user.apply_async(countdown=5)
and here's how I set up the celery.py file:
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'base.settings')

app = Celery('base', broker="amqps://guest:guest@localhost:5671/")

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

I've tried to do “celery status” to see the worker status but I get this error:
# /home/transcendence/venv/bin/celery status
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 515, in channel
    return self.channels[channel_id]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 15, in main
    sys.exit(_main())
             ^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 236, in main
    return celery(auto_envvar_prefix="CELERY")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 33, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 135, in caller
    return f(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/bin/control.py", line 133, in status
    callback=callback).ping()
                       ^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 294, in ping
    return self._request('ping')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 106, in _request
    return self._prepare(self.app.control.broadcast(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 776, in broadcast
    return self.mailbox(conn)._broadcast(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 330, in _broadcast
    chan = channel or self.connection.default_channel
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 956, in default_channel
    self._default_channel = self.channel()
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 303, in channel
    chan = self.transport.create_channel(self.connection)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 168, in create_channel
    return connection.channel()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 518, in channel
    channel.open()
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 448, in open
    return self.send_method(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 79, in send_method
    return self.wait(wait, returns_tuple=returns_tuple)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 99, in wait
    self.connection.drain_events(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 526, in drain_events
    while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 531, in blocking_read
    frame = self.transport.read_frame()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 294, in read_frame
    frame_header = read(7, True)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/transcendence/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 629, in _read
    s = recv(n - len(rbuf))
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

and I tried to look at the rabbitmq logs where you can see that there's a connection when I do delete_user.apply_async(countdown=5):
2024-04-30 14:30:55.853808+00:00 [info] <0.716.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.716.0> (127.0.0.1:34092 -> 127.0.0.1:5671)
2024-04-30 14:30:55.856889+00:00 [info] <0.716.0> connection <0.716.0> (127.0.0.1:34092 -> 127.0.0.1:5671): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'


Printing might not be the best way to test if Celery tasks are being executed. The print statement might or might not be logged depending on your logging config. I'd recommend doing something else, like incrementing a value in your database. That would be easier to check.

it's true that print is not the right way to test thank you for the advice, I just tried and it doesn't work, I have no error  (except when I do celery status) but nothing happens in the database. :(

i couldn't find the source of the error but i managed to solve the problem by replacing rabbitmq with redis.
